# How to get data from mongodb in nodejs and angular

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular8

I am trying to get data from mongodb to show in a table but not working.I am new in nodejs so anyone can help to find a solution?

If i open this url i am getting like this: 
http://localhost:3000/api/getTableData

{"status":true,"table":{}}

table.modal.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product_name: {
        type: String
    },
    price: {
        type: String
    },
    catogery: {
        type: String
    }
});

mongoose.model('table', userSchema);
```

table.controller.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const _ = require('lodash');

const Table = mongoose.model('table');

var table = new Table();
/*Get Table Data*/

module.exports.getTableData = (req, res, next) => {

Table.find({ _id: req._id },
    (err, table) => {
        if (!table)
            return res.status(404).json({ status: false, message: 'Table data records not found.' });
        else
            return res.status(200).json({ status: true, table: _.pick(table, ['product_name', 'price', 'category']) });
    }
); 
 }
```

index.router.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();  
const ctrlTable = require('../controllers/table.controller'); 
router.get('/getTableData', ctrlTable.getTableData); 
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are there a mistake in your code? Instead of use `req._id`  you should use `req.params._id`. Can you put your route definition? for me is not clear how it is using `_id`

Comment: @Danizavtz: index.router js file added.Please check it

Comment: What does the document you are trying to match look like?

Comment: Working now. NP